# Why do Facetime and Messages ask me for a password at random moments?

Tags: macos, messages, facetime, authentication

Facetime and Messages have started asking me for my username and password at seemingly random moments.

I don't use either application and have not added them to my login's autostart programs.

This is happening on 10.8.5.

Comment: Did you change your iCloud password?

Comment: Not very recently, no.

Comment: Understand that I find it odd because I have never used those applications and never planned to. I don't know why they even ask for my username and password.

Comment: The message boxes still appear every now and then and ask for my username and password. I still don't use either application.